# PLUpload not working with Extj 5

Tags: extjs, extjs4, plupload, extjs5

Please find the fiddles for PLUpload against Extjs 4 and 5

```
Fiddle with Extjs 4 [WORKING]

    http://jsfiddle.net/jaspreets/dvsbsgse/

Fiddle with Extjs 5 [NOT WORKING]

    http://jsfiddle.net/jaspreets/797sLzsn/
```

Please tell me why it is not working with ExtJs - 5 .
What can be the possible solution for this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to migrate PLUpload plugin. For that you need to have several changes in the plugin.

Button.js:

```
/**
* @class Ext.ux.upload.Button
* @extends Ext.button.Button
*
* @author Harald Hanek (c) 2011-2012
* @license http://harrydeluxe.mit-license.org
*/
Ext.define('Ext.util.multiupload.Button', {
  extend: 'Ext.button.Button',
  alias: 'widget.uploadbutton',
  requires: ['Ext.util.multiupload.Basic'],
  disabled: true,

  listeners: {
    boxready: function() {
        var me = this;
        Ext.applyIf(me.config.uploader, {
            browse_button: me.config.id || me.getId()
        });

        me.uploader = me.createUploader();
        me.uploader.initialize();
        me.plugins[0].initializeComponent(me);

        me.relayEvents(me.uploader, ['beforestart',
            'uploadready',
            'uploadstarted',
            'uploadcomplete',
            'uploaderror',
            'filesadded',
            'beforeupload',
            'fileuploaded',
            'updateprogress',
            'uploadprogress',
            'storeempty'
        ]);
    }
},

/**
 * @private
 */
createUploader: function() {
    return Ext.create('Ext.util.multiupload.Basic', this, Ext.applyIf({
        listeners: {}
    }, this.initialConfig));
}
});
```

Basic.js:
Remove AddEvents. Change Store to this.

```
me.store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
        fields: ['id', 'loaded', 'name', 'size', 'percent', 'status', 'msg'],
        listeners: {
            load: me.onStoreLoad,
            remove: me.onStoreRemove,
            update: me.onStoreUpdate,
            scope: me
        }
    });
```

Second argument of onStoreRemove method is an array. So take first element.

Window.js:
Remove Id "form-statusbar". Rename init function to initializeComponent.

It should be working now.